# Best way to insert all the combinations

Tags: mysql

I have been thinking about it for quite a bit and can't seem to figure out a way to do it in plain mysql.

I have a list of words (size is not fixed):

- word11
- word21
- word31
- word41

For each one of those words, I have a list of synonyms (size is not fixed). For word11, for intance:

- word12
- word13
- word14
- word15
- word16

my goal would be to get all the different possibibilities:

- word11 word21 word31 word41
- word12 word21 word31 word41
- word13 word21 word31 word41
- word14 word21 word31 word41
- ...
- word11 word21 word31 word417
- word11 word21 word31 word418

I thought about using a temporary table to store the different results.

For each word, and for each result stored in the temporary table, insert the new synonyms instead.

The first iteration for word11 would give

- word11 word21 word31 word41
- word12 word21 word31 word41
- word13 word21 word31 word41
- word14 word21 word31 word41
- word15 word21 word31 word41
- word16 word21 word31 word41

For iteration 2, for each one of these entries, insert the synonyms by replacing word21 by its synonyms.

But that seems very tedious and there might be a better way (not even sure it would be close to actually work).

Any hint?

Comment: So this is a question about permutations or combinations?

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, it's about combinations. word11 will never be in the last position for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support recursive or hierarchical queries, which are what is really needed for this.  For a fixed number of words, you can do:

```
select w1.synonym, w2.synonym, w3.synonym, w4.synonym
from synonyms w1 cross join
     synonyms w2 cross join
     synonyms w3 cross join
     synonyms w4
where w1.word = 'word1' and
      w2.word = 'word2' and
      w3.word = 'word3' and
      w4.word = 'word4';
```

(In actual fact, the query would be more complicated unless you have a word be its own synonym, but that is an easy-enough fix to the above query).

In order to add more words, you need more joins, alas.  If you have a fixed number, then you can hardcode it.  Otherwise, you can generate the SQL as a prepared statement and then execute.  The particular SQL would be something like:

```
   select concat('select ', group_concat('w_', word, '.word' separator ', '),
                 ' from ',
                 group_concat('synonyms w_', word separator ' cross join '),
                 ' where ',
                 group_concat('w_', word, ' = ''', word, '''' separator ' and '
                )
   from words w;
```

Comment: With MySQL 5.5.8 synonyms may not be a temporary table as it seems a temporary table can only be accessed once per query. Hope this has been changed for the better in more recent versions and OP is not affected.